# ListCollectionView GroupDescription issue

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class called ContactList that has a property called AggLabels which is an Observable Collection. When a ContactList gets populated the AggLabels collection will contain some duplicate AggregatedLabels. Is there a way to group these AggregatedLabels by "Name" using a ListCollectionView so that duplicates are not displayed when I bind the collection to a listBox in WPF? The code in my snippet groups by ContactListName is there a way I can modify this to achieve my goal? Thanks

**ContactList**

```
public class ContactList
{           
    public int ContactListID { get; set; }
    public string ContactListName { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<AggregatedLabel> AggLabels { get; set; }
}
```

**AggregatedLabel**

```
public class AggregatedLabel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

**Code Snippet**

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //TODO: Add event handler implementation here.

        ListCollectionView lcv = new ListCollectionView(myContactLists);

        lcv.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("ContactListName"));

        contactsListBox.ItemsSource = lcv.Groups;

    }
```

Comment: Could you clarify your example with concrete values in ContactList, AggLables and output you are expecting?

Comment: Yes, so my ContactListID and ContactListName are always unique, the AggLabels have unique ID's but the Name can be duplicated. E.g for one ContactList object it could be ContactListID = 01, ContactListName = List1 and then the AggLabel collection could contain ID = 01 and Name = AggLabel, ID = 02 and Name = AggLabel, ID = 03 and Name = NewAggLabel. Hope this makes sense?

Comment: Actually no, you asked about non-duplicated values in AggLabels, but I can't see usage of AggLabels (i.e. where you have got duplicated AggLabels). In your code snippet groupping by ContactListName (which is unique) is executed, and I suppose that somewhere else you have ComboBoxItem DataTemplate that contains duplicated AggLabels. Am I right?

Comment: Yes thats right. Is there a better way I can make sure that my DataTemplate does not display duplicated AggLabel.Names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have not provided information about AggLabels usage I hope this solution will help:

```
    <ComboBox Name="contactsListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ContactListName}"/>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AggLabels, Converter={StaticResource Conv}}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>

public class AggLabelsDistictConverter : IValueConverter
{
    class AggregatedLabelComparer : IEqualityComparer<AggregatedLabel>
    {

        #region IEqualityComparer<AggregatedLabel> Members

        public bool Equals(AggregatedLabel x, AggregatedLabel y)
        {
            return x.Name == y.Name;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(AggregatedLabel obj)
        {
            return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is IEnumerable<AggregatedLabel>)
        {
            var list = (IEnumerable<AggregatedLabel>)value;
            return list.Distinct(new AggregatedLabelComparer());
        }}}
```

As you can see I bind ContactListEnumerable in usual way, and AggLabels list inside every ContactList container - via converter that removes duplicates.